# Call to a member function _kohana_load_view() on a non-object

Tags: kohana

I just hosted a kohana based application on url http://demosite007.freeiz.com/. I am getting the following error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function
>   _kohana_load_view() on a non-object in /home/a7397954/public_html/system/framework/libraries/View.php
>   on line 272.

There has been no changes to this file. I had hosted the same application on other servers, it was working perfectly fine. I hope someone out there can help. thanks in advance.

Comment: http://forum.kohanaframework.org/discussion/344/call-to-a-member-function-_kohana_load_view-on-a-non-object/p1 could maybe help

Answer (score 1):

The logging was enabled. So at the initialization level, the system was trying to update the log files. The logs directory did not have WRITE permission because of which the particular error was thrown.

Comment: hey@pranav_kavi how can i do that my kohana applicaton in online